# Actors with shared state

Tags: swift, concurrency, actor

The following two actors share the same URLSession instance. The actors work in isolation, so is this a problem because each actor may change properties on the session at the same time? How can I protect against this?

```
actor ImageDownloaderA {
    
    let session = URLSession.shared
    
    func fetchImage() async throws -> Data {
        let request = ...
        return try await session.data(for: ...)
    }
}

actor ImageDownloaderB {
    
    let session = URLSession.shared
    
    func fetchImage() async throws -> Data {
        let request = ...
        return try await session.data(for: ...)
    }
}

struct Fetcher {
    
    func fetcher() async throws {
        let downloaderA = ImageDownloaderA()
        let downloaderB = ImageDownloaderB()
        _ = try await downloaderA.fetchImage()
        _ = try await downloaderB.fetchImage()
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "change properties" and what the properties are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`URLSession` is `Sendable` and is safe to be passed across concurrency domains. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession) also explicitly tells us that it is thread-safe:

> #### Thread Safety
>
> The URL session API is thread-safe. You can freely create sessions and
> tasks in any thread context. When your delegate methods call the
> provided completion handlers, the work is automatically scheduled on
> the correct delegate queue.

---

It should be noted that these two requests are not actually executing concurrently. This is not because of `URLSession`, but rather because this code will `await` the completion of `ImageDownloaderA.fetchImage` before even starting `ImageDownloaderB.fetchImage`. If we want concurrent execution, we might use `async let` or a task group.

Now, you’re not showing us what you’re doing with these two responses, but let’s imagine that for demonstration purposes you wanted them to simply print the number of bytes that each returned.

```swift
func fetcher() async throws {
    let downloaderA = ImageDownloaderA()
    let downloaderB = ImageDownloaderB()

    async let data1 = downloaderA.fetchImage()
    async let data2 = downloaderB.fetchImage()
    
    let count1 = try await data1.count
    let count2 = try await data2.count
    
    print(count1, count2)
}
```

That will run the requests concurrently because we used `async let` and then only introduced `await` suspension points after both had been started. For details on `async let`, see [SE-0317](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0317-async-let.md).

---

But, regardless, you can use the same `URLSession` in separate concurrency contexts without incident.